# How dows Ketchup (gottaketchup.com) send facebook messages?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, api, omniauth

I've been searching all day and everything I can find indicates that it is impossible to send a message to a user's facebook friends via the Graph API.  I understand that I can send a link as a facebook message, but that requires a link url and does not allow the message itself to be pre-populated.  However, the app Ketchup lets you send an actual FB message to friends inviting them to do activities with you.  It's not an app request and has a custom message that is not required to be filled out.  Are they using the send dialog and somehow skipping the popup window, or is there actually another way to send messages to a user's friends?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are most likely using the Chat API *but* they really shouldn't, this could blow up in their face. It's not that clever of a circumvention, risking your app being banned.

> Your Facebook Chat integration should only be used for applications facilitating real time conversation or interaction between users. Links or advertisements should not be sent via chat, unless the sending user types in this message

[image: Chat permissions]

In any case using require 'xmpp4r_facebook'

```
id = '-<sender user id>@chat.facebook.com'
to = '-<user id>@chat.facebook.com'
body = "hello, Im not spam!"
subject = 'message from ruby'
message = Jabber::Message.new to, body
message.subject = subject

client = Jabber::Client.new Jabber::JID.new(id)
client.connect
client.auth_sasl(Jabber::SASL::XFacebookPlatform.new(client, '<App ID/API Key>', '<Access Token>', '<App Secret>'), nil)
client.send message
client.close
```

With `xmpp_login` permission

**This is just proof of concept, incorporating this in your app to send messages to users in a non-realtime format may result in consequences for your application**

Comment: It appears that their strategy has indeed blown up in their face, at least a little bit.  The messages I have sent through the app now are listed as no longer available because they appeared to be abusive or spam.